# Average function in PostgreSQL with 5 minutes tolerance

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, time-series, average, temporal-database

I have a temporal database and I want to aggregate by the average function every HH instantaneous values with 5 minute before and 5 minute after. Frequency of data samplying is 2 minutes and the data includes timestamps and temperature columns.
First of all, the code should extract the instantaneous values from 00, 01, 02, 03, ... 24 and then apply 2 observation of before and 2 observations of after the instantaneous hours.
 Moreover, in db sometimes minutes are odd and sometimes they are even. So, we have both HH-1:59 and HH:00 . The average value obtains from mean of 5 values. The format of the date_time column is timestamps. Moreover the code should can handle multiple days data.

Sample data:

```
   dt          ambtemp
       "2007-09-29 00:11:09+02";-1.87
    "2007-09-29 00:13:09+02";-1.87
    "2007-09-29 00:15:09+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 00:17:09+02";-1.64
    "2007-09-29 00:19:09+02";-1.6
    "2007-09-29 00:21:09+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 00:23:09+02";-2.08
    "2007-09-29 00:25:09+02";-1.94
    "2007-09-29 00:27:09+02";-2.12
    "2007-09-29 00:29:09+02";-1.87
    "2007-09-29 00:31:09+02";-2.18
    "2007-09-29 00:33:09+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 00:35:09+02";-1.73
    "2007-09-29 00:37:09+02";-1.84
    "2007-09-29 00:39:09+02";-2.04
    "2007-09-29 00:41:09+02";-1.86
    "2007-09-29 00:43:09+02";-1.94
    "2007-09-29 00:45:09+02";-1.77
    "2007-09-29 00:47:09+02";-1.78
    "2007-09-29 00:49:09+02";-1.5
    "2007-09-29 00:51:09+02";-1.46
    "2007-09-29 00:53:09+02";-1.72
    "2007-09-29 00:55:09+02";-1.67
    "2007-09-29 00:57:09+02";-1.56
    "2007-09-29 00:59:09+02";-1.69
    "2007-09-29 01:01:09+02";-1.97
    "2007-09-29 01:03:09+02";-1.79
    "2007-09-29 01:05:09+02";-1.79
    "2007-09-29 01:07:09+02";-1.84
    "2007-09-29 01:09:09+02";-1.91
    "2007-09-29 01:11:09+02";-1.87
    "2007-09-29 01:13:09+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 01:15:09+02";-1.83
    "2007-09-29 01:17:09+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 01:19:09+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 01:21:09+02";-1.78
    "2007-09-29 01:23:09+02";-1.78
    "2007-09-29 01:25:09+02";-1.66
    "2007-09-29 01:27:09+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 01:29:09+02";-1.46
    "2007-09-29 01:31:09+02";-1.36
    "2007-09-29 01:33:09+02";-1.4
    "2007-09-29 01:35:09+02";-1.34
    "2007-09-29 01:37:09+02";-1.34
    "2007-09-29 01:39:09+02";-1.3
    "2007-09-29 01:41:09+02";-1.36
    "2007-09-29 01:43:09+02";-1.4
    "2007-09-29 01:45:09+02";-1.43
    "2007-09-29 01:47:09+02";-1.38
    "2007-09-29 01:49:09+02";-1.4
    "2007-09-29 01:51:09+02";-1.42
    "2007-09-29 01:53:09+02";-1.47
    "2007-09-29 01:55:09+02";-1.66
    "2007-09-29 01:57:09+02";-1.84
    "2007-09-29 01:59:09+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 02:01:09+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 02:03:09+02";-2.11
    "2007-09-29 02:05:09+02";-1.91
    "2007-09-29 02:07:09+02";-2.04
    "2007-09-29 02:09:09+02";-1.94
    "2007-09-29 02:11:09+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 02:13:09+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 02:15:09+02";-1.74
    "2007-09-29 02:17:09+02";-1.74
    "2007-09-29 02:19:09+02";-1.76
    "2007-09-29 02:21:09+02";-1.74
    "2007-09-29 02:23:09+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 02:25:09+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 02:27:09+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 02:29:09+02";-1.82
    "2007-09-29 02:31:09+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 02:33:09+02";-1.93
    "2007-09-29 02:35:09+02";-2.06
    "2007-09-29 02:37:09+02";-2.08
    "2007-09-29 02:39:09+02";-1.95
    "2007-09-29 02:41:09+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 02:43:09+02";-2.32
    "2007-09-29 02:45:09+02";-1.86
    "2007-09-29 02:47:09+02";-1.97
    "2007-09-29 02:49:09+02";-1.64
    "2007-09-29 02:51:09+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 02:53:09+02";-1.48
    "2007-09-29 02:55:09+02";-1.74
    "2007-09-29 02:57:09+02";-1.85
    "2007-09-29 02:59:09+02";-1.82
    "2007-09-29 03:01:09+02";-1.82
    "2007-09-29 03:03:09+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 03:05:09+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 03:07:09+02";-1.54
    "2007-09-29 03:09:09+02";-1.36
    "2007-09-29 03:11:09+02";-1.5
    "2007-09-29 03:13:09+02";-1.59
    "2007-09-29 03:15:09+02";-1.6
    "2007-09-29 03:17:09+02";-1.58
    "2007-09-29 03:19:09+02";-1.81
    "2007-09-29 03:21:09+02";-2.16
    "2007-09-29 03:23:09+02";-1.97
    "2007-09-29 03:25:09+02";-1.94
    "2007-09-29 03:27:09+02";-2.29
    "2007-09-29 03:29:09+02";-2.46
    "2007-09-29 03:31:09+02";-2.42
    "2007-09-29 03:33:09+02";-2.34
    "2007-09-29 03:35:09+02";-2.38
    "2007-09-29 03:37:09+02";-2.44
    "2007-09-29 03:39:09+02";-2.28
    "2007-09-29 03:41:09+02";-2.24
    "2007-09-29 03:43:09+02";-2.26
    "2007-09-29 03:45:09+02";-2.05
    "2007-09-29 03:47:09+02";-2.38
    "2007-09-29 03:49:09+02";-2.24
    "2007-09-29 03:51:09+02";-2.46
    "2007-09-29 03:53:09+02";-2.22
    "2007-09-29 03:55:09+02";-2.24
    "2007-09-29 03:57:09+02";-2.2
    "2007-09-29 03:59:09+02";-2.28
    "2007-09-29 04:01:09+02";-1.86
    "2007-09-29 04:03:09+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 04:05:09+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 04:07:09+02";-1.99
    "2007-09-29 04:09:09+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 04:11:09+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 04:13:09+02";-2.13
    "2007-09-29 04:15:09+02";-2.11
    "2007-09-29 04:17:09+02";-2.1
    "2007-09-29 04:19:09+02";-2.28
    "2007-09-29 04:21:09+02";-2.28
    "2007-09-29 04:23:09+02";-2.44
    "2007-09-29 04:25:09+02";-2.44
    "2007-09-29 04:27:08+02";-2.2
    "2007-09-29 04:29:08+02";-2.2
    "2007-09-29 04:31:08+02";-2.11
    "2007-09-29 04:31:09+02";-2.11
    "2007-09-29 04:33:09+02";-2.3
    "2007-09-29 04:35:09+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 04:37:08+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 04:39:08+02";-1.43
    "2007-09-29 04:41:08+02";-1.55
    "2007-09-29 04:43:09+02";-1.43
    "2007-09-29 04:45:09+02";-1.59
    "2007-09-29 04:47:08+02";-1.58
    "2007-09-29 04:49:08+02";-1.52
    "2007-09-29 04:51:08+02";-1.5
    "2007-09-29 04:53:09+02";-1.4
    "2007-09-29 04:55:08+02";-1.46
    "2007-09-29 04:55:09+02";-1.46
    "2007-09-29 04:57:08+02";-1.5
    "2007-09-29 04:59:08+02";-1.52
    "2007-09-29 05:01:08+02";-1.64
    "2007-09-29 05:03:08+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 05:05:08+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 05:07:08+02";-1.71
    "2007-09-29 05:09:08+02";-1.96
    "2007-09-29 05:11:08+02";-2.03
    "2007-09-29 05:13:08+02";-2.18
    "2007-09-29 05:15:08+02";-2.2
    "2007-09-29 05:17:08+02";-1.91
    "2007-09-29 05:19:08+02";-2.06
    "2007-09-29 05:21:08+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 05:23:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 05:25:08+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 05:27:08+02";-1.86
    "2007-09-29 05:29:08+02";-2.08
    "2007-09-29 05:31:08+02";-2.03
    "2007-09-29 05:33:08+02";-1.83
    "2007-09-29 05:35:08+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 05:37:08+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 05:39:08+02";-1.6
    "2007-09-29 05:41:08+02";-1.64
    "2007-09-29 05:43:08+02";-1.65
    "2007-09-29 05:45:08+02";-1.67
    "2007-09-29 05:47:08+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 05:49:08+02";-1.82
    "2007-09-29 05:51:08+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 05:53:08+02";-1.91
    "2007-09-29 05:55:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 05:57:08+02";-1.93
    "2007-09-29 05:59:08+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 06:01:08+02";-2.04
    "2007-09-29 06:03:08+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 06:05:08+02";-1.96
    "2007-09-29 06:07:08+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 06:09:08+02";-1.93
    "2007-09-29 06:11:08+02";-1.78
    "2007-09-29 06:13:08+02";-1.73
    "2007-09-29 06:15:08+02";-1.76
    "2007-09-29 06:17:08+02";-1.67
    "2007-09-29 06:19:08+02";-1.68
    "2007-09-29 06:21:08+02";-1.38
    "2007-09-29 06:23:08+02";-1.33
    "2007-09-29 06:25:07+02";-1.31
    "2007-09-29 06:27:08+02";-1.34
    "2007-09-29 06:29:08+02";-1.28
    "2007-09-29 06:31:08+02";-1.28
    "2007-09-29 06:33:07+02";-1.51
    "2007-09-29 06:35:08+02";-1.76
    "2007-09-29 06:37:08+02";-1.84
    "2007-09-29 06:39:08+02";-1.89
    "2007-09-29 06:41:08+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 06:43:08+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 06:45:08+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 06:47:08+02";-1.96
    "2007-09-29 06:49:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 06:51:08+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 06:53:07+02";-1.79
    "2007-09-29 06:55:07+02";-1.73
    "2007-09-29 06:57:08+02";-1.7
    "2007-09-29 06:59:07+02";-1.72
    "2007-09-29 07:01:08+02";-1.74
    "2007-09-29 07:03:08+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 07:05:08+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 07:07:08+02";-1.84
    "2007-09-29 07:09:08+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 07:11:08+02";-1.89
    "2007-09-29 07:13:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:15:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:17:08+02";-1.96
    "2007-09-29 07:19:07+02";-1.98
    "2007-09-29 07:21:08+02";-2
    "2007-09-29 07:23:07+02";-1.96
    "2007-09-29 07:25:08+02";-1.94
    "2007-09-29 07:27:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:29:07+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:31:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:33:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:35:08+02";-1.94
    "2007-09-29 07:37:08+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 07:39:08+02";-1.92
    "2007-09-29 07:41:08+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 07:43:07+02";-1.9
    "2007-09-29 07:45:08+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 07:47:08+02";-1.85
    "2007-09-29 07:49:08+02";-1.86
    "2007-09-29 07:51:07+02";-1.87
    "2007-09-29 07:53:08+02";-1.72
    "2007-09-29 07:55:08+02";-1.55
    "2007-09-29 07:57:08+02";-1.52
    "2007-09-29 07:59:08+02";-1.53
    "2007-09-29 08:01:08+02";-1.54
    "2007-09-29 08:03:08+02";-1.6
    "2007-09-29 08:05:08+02";-1.77
    "2007-09-29 08:07:08+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 08:09:08+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 08:11:08+02";-1.8
    "2007-09-29 08:13:08+02";-1.96
    "2007-09-29 08:15:09+02";-1.88
    "2007-09-29 08:17:08+02";-1.44
    "2007-09-29 08:19:08+02";-1.34
    "2007-09-29 08:21:08+02";-1.22
    "2007-09-29 08:23:08+02";-1.34
    "2007-09-29 08:25:09+02";-1.24
    "2007-09-29 08:27:09+02";-0.66
    "2007-09-29 08:29:09+02";-0.98
    "2007-09-29 08:31:09+02";-1.1
    "2007-09-29 08:33:08+02";0.1
    "2007-09-29 08:35:09+02";0.27
    "2007-09-29 08:37:09+02";-0.14
    "2007-09-29 08:39:08+02";-0.52
    "2007-09-29 08:41:08+02";-1
    "2007-09-29 08:43:08+02";-0.58
    "2007-09-29 08:45:08+02";-0.7
    "2007-09-29 08:47:08+02";-0.6
    "2007-09-29 08:49:08+02";-0.87
    "2007-09-29 08:51:08+02";-0.44
    "2007-09-29 08:53:08+02";-0.69
    "2007-09-29 08:55:08+02";-0.14
    "2007-09-29 08:57:08+02";0.12
    "2007-09-29 08:59:08+02";-0.37
    "2007-09-29 09:01:08+02";0.32
    "2007-09-29 09:03:07+02";0.04
    "2007-09-29 09:05:07+02";0.3
    "2007-09-29 09:07:07+02";0.32
    "2007-09-29 09:09:07+02";-0.2
    "2007-09-29 09:11:07+02";-0.07
    "2007-09-29 09:13:07+02";0.11
    "2007-09-29 09:15:07+02";0.34
    "2007-09-29 09:17:07+02";0.58
    "2007-09-29 09:19:07+02";0.46
    "2007-09-29 09:21:07+02";-0.27
    "2007-09-29 09:23:07+02";-0.57
    "2007-09-29 09:25:07+02";-0.2
    "2007-09-29 09:27:07+02";0
    "2007-09-29 09:29:07+02";-0.04
    "2007-09-29 09:31:07+02";-0.77
    "2007-09-29 09:33:07+02";-0.3
    "2007-09-29 09:35:07+02";0.34
    "2007-09-29 09:37:07+02";0.1
    "2007-09-29 09:39:07+02";0.05
    "2007-09-29 09:41:07+02";0.18
    "2007-09-29 09:43:07+02";1.2
    "2007-09-29 09:45:07+02";1.84
    "2007-09-29 09:47:07+02";0.93
    "2007-09-29 09:49:07+02";0.58
    "2007-09-29 09:51:07+02";-0.22
    "2007-09-29 09:53:07+02";0.09
    "2007-09-29 09:55:07+02";0.28
    "2007-09-29 09:57:07+02";1.4
    "2007-09-29 09:59:07+02";1.38
    "2007-09-29 10:01:07+02";2
    "2007-09-29 10:03:07+02";2.16
    "2007-09-29 10:05:07+02";2.48
    "2007-09-29 10:07:07+02";2.8
    "2007-09-29 10:09:07+02";1.66
    "2007-09-29 10:11:07+02";1.56
    "2007-09-29 10:13:07+02";1.49
    "2007-09-29 10:15:07+02";0.86
    "2007-09-29 10:17:07+02";1.37
    "2007-09-29 10:19:07+02";1.16
    "2007-09-29 10:21:07+02";1.16
    "2007-09-29 10:23:07+02";1.6
    "2007-09-29 10:25:07+02";0.84
    "2007-09-29 10:27:07+02";2.14
    "2007-09-29 10:29:07+02";2.25
    "2007-09-29 10:31:07+02";2.25
    "2007-09-29 10:33:07+02";2.12
    "2007-09-29 10:35:07+02";1.68
    "2007-09-29 10:37:07+02";2.14
    "2007-09-29 10:39:07+02";1.1
    "2007-09-29 10:41:07+02";1.23
    "2007-09-29 10:43:07+02";1.4
    "2007-09-29 10:45:07+02";1.78
    "2007-09-29 10:47:07+02";1.36
    "2007-09-29 10:49:07+02";2.26
    "2007-09-29 10:51:07+02";1.8
    "2007-09-29 10:53:07+02";2.08
    "2007-09-29 10:55:07+02";1.96
    "2007-09-29 10:57:07+02";2.46
    "2007-09-29 10:59:07+02";2.69
    "2007-09-29 11:01:07+02";2.24
    "2007-09-29 11:03:07+02";1.59
    "2007-09-29 11:05:07+02";1.74
    "2007-09-29 11:07:07+02";1.38
    "2007-09-29 11:09:07+02";1.97
    "2007-09-29 11:11:07+02";2.06
    "2007-09-29 11:13:07+02";1.64
    "2007-09-29 11:15:07+02";2.22
    "2007-09-29 11:17:07+02";3.07
    "2007-09-29 11:19:07+02";1.98
    "2007-09-29 11:21:07+02";2.88
    "2007-09-29 11:23:07+02";2.9
    "2007-09-29 11:25:07+02";1.62
    "2007-09-29 11:27:07+02";1.79
    "2007-09-29 11:29:07+02";2.7
    "2007-09-29 11:31:07+02";1.96
    "2007-09-29 11:33:07+02";2.9
    "2007-09-29 11:35:07+02";2.76
    "2007-09-29 11:37:07+02";2.08
    "2007-09-29 11:39:07+02";2.88
    "2007-09-29 11:41:07+02";2.55
    "2007-09-29 11:43:07+02";2.49
    "2007-09-29 11:45:07+02";2.52
    "2007-09-29 11:47:07+02";2.68
    "2007-09-29 11:49:07+02";3.1
    "2007-09-29 11:51:07+02";3.72
    "2007-09-29 11:53:07+02";2.94
    "2007-09-29 11:55:07+02";3.86
    "2007-09-29 11:57:07+02";3.76
    "2007-09-29 11:59:07+02";2.8
    "2007-09-29 12:01:07+02";2.28
    "2007-09-29 12:03:07+02";2.8
    "2007-09-29 12:05:07+02";3.1
    "2007-09-29 12:07:07+02";2.63
    "2007-09-29 12:09:07+02";2.76
    "2007-09-29 12:11:07+02";4.02
    "2007-09-29 12:13:07+02";3.47
    "2007-09-29 12:15:07+02";3.2
    "2007-09-29 12:17:07+02";2.65
    "2007-09-29 12:19:07+02";4.11
    "2007-09-29 12:21:07+02";2.66
    "2007-09-29 12:23:07+02";4.34
    "2007-09-29 12:25:07+02";4.1
    "2007-09-29 12:27:07+02";4.17
    "2007-09-29 12:29:07+02";3.16
    "2007-09-29 12:31:07+02";3.98
    "2007-09-29 12:33:07+02";3.72
    "2007-09-29 12:35:07+02";3.66
    "2007-09-29 12:37:07+02";3.26
    "2007-09-29 12:39:07+02";4.5
    "2007-09-29 12:41:07+02";3.94
    "2007-09-29 12:43:07+02";4.11
    "2007-09-29 12:45:07+02";3.89
    "2007-09-29 12:47:06+02";3.22
    "2007-09-29 12:49:06+02";4.26
    "2007-09-29 12:51:06+02";4.98
    "2007-09-29 12:53:06+02";4.46
    "2007-09-29 12:55:06+02";4.86
    "2007-09-29 12:57:07+02";3.91
    "2007-09-29 12:59:07+02";3.56
    "2007-09-29 13:01:07+02";5.27
    "2007-09-29 13:03:07+02";4.12
    "2007-09-29 13:05:07+02";5.07
    "2007-09-29 13:07:06+02";4.16
    "2007-09-29 13:09:06+02";4.56
    "2007-09-29 13:11:06+02";4.24
    "2007-09-29 13:13:06+02";4.34
    "2007-09-29 13:15:06+02";4.63
    "2007-09-29 13:17:06+02";4.68
    "2007-09-29 13:19:06+02";3.71
    "2007-09-29 13:21:06+02";3.79
    "2007-09-29 13:23:06+02";4.61
    "2007-09-29 13:25:06+02";4.95
    "2007-09-29 13:27:06+02";4.66
    "2007-09-29 13:29:06+02";4.32
    "2007-09-29 13:31:06+02";3.98
    "2007-09-29 13:33:06+02";5.43
    "2007-09-29 13:35:06+02";4.38
    "2007-09-29 13:37:06+02";4.39
    "2007-09-29 13:39:06+02";4.7
    "2007-09-29 13:41:06+02";4.34
    "2007-09-29 13:43:06+02";5.56
    "2007-09-29 13:45:06+02";4.61
    "2007-09-29 13:47:06+02";4.58
    "2007-09-29 13:49:06+02";4.81
    "2007-09-29 13:51:06+02";5.04
    "2007-09-29 13:53:06+02";5.74
    "2007-09-29 13:55:06+02";4.92
    "2007-09-29 13:57:06+02";4.65
    "2007-09-29 13:59:06+02";5.08
    "2007-09-29 14:01:06+02";4.9
    "2007-09-29 14:03:06+02";4.34
    "2007-09-29 14:05:06+02";5.42
    "2007-09-29 14:07:06+02";5.58
    "2007-09-29 14:09:06+02";4.98
    "2007-09-29 14:11:06+02";4.91
    "2007-09-29 14:13:06+02";5.44
    "2007-09-29 14:15:06+02";4.62
    "2007-09-29 14:17:06+02";5.36
    "2007-09-29 14:19:06+02";4.56
    "2007-09-29 14:21:06+02";4.77
    "2007-09-29 14:23:06+02";4.88
    "2007-09-29 14:25:06+02";4.29
    "2007-09-29 14:27:06+02";4.43
    "2007-09-29 14:29:06+02";4.78
    "2007-09-29 14:31:06+02";5.06
    "2007-09-29 14:33:06+02";4.83
    "2007-09-29 14:35:06+02";4.44
    "2007-09-29 14:37:06+02";5.48
    "2007-09-29 14:39:06+02";4.9
    "2007-09-29 14:41:06+02";4.42
    "2007-09-29 14:43:06+02";4.82
    "2007-09-29 14:45:06+02";4.9
    "2007-09-29 14:47:06+02";4.76
    "2007-09-29 14:49:06+02";5.48
    "2007-09-29 14:51:06+02";5.48
    "2007-09-29 14:53:06+02";5.46
    "2007-09-29 14:55:06+02";5.54
    "2007-09-29 14:57:06+02";5.53
    "2007-09-29 14:59:06+02";5.5
    "2007-09-29 15:01:06+02";5.33
    "2007-09-29 15:03:06+02";6.18
    "2007-09-29 15:05:06+02";4.91
    "2007-09-29 15:07:06+02";5.08
    "2007-09-29 15:09:06+02";4.71
    "2007-09-29 15:11:06+02";4.49
    "2007-09-29 15:13:06+02";5.47
    "2007-09-29 15:15:06+02";4.58
    "2007-09-29 15:17:06+02";4.75
    "2007-09-29 15:19:06+02";5.46
    "2007-09-29 15:21:06+02";5.39
    "2007-09-29 15:23:06+02";5.59
    "2007-09-29 15:25:06+02";5.76
    "2007-09-29 15:27:06+02";5.08
    "2007-09-29 15:29:06+02";5.96
    "2007-09-29 15:31:06+02";4.9
    "2007-09-29 15:33:06+02";5.36
    "2007-09-29 15:35:06+02";5.08
    "2007-09-29 15:37:06+02";5.93
    "2007-09-29 15:39:06+02";5.34
    "2007-09-29 15:41:06+02";5.24
    "2007-09-29 15:43:06+02";5.78
    "2007-09-29 15:45:06+02";6.58
    "2007-09-29 15:47:06+02";6.09
    "2007-09-29 15:49:06+02";5.4
    "2007-09-29 15:51:06+02";6.18
    "2007-09-29 15:53:06+02";5.79
    "2007-09-29 15:55:06+02";5.36
    "2007-09-29 15:57:06+02";5.8
    "2007-09-29 15:59:07+02";6.06
    "2007-09-29 16:01:06+02";5.7
    "2007-09-29 16:03:07+02";5.58
    "2007-09-29 16:05:07+02";6.5
    "2007-09-29 16:07:07+02";5.83
    "2007-09-29 16:09:07+02";5.54
    "2007-09-29 16:11:06+02";5.8
    "2007-09-29 16:13:06+02";6.03
    "2007-09-29 16:15:06+02";5.54
    "2007-09-29 16:17:07+02";5.56
    "2007-09-29 16:19:07+02";6.04
    "2007-09-29 16:21:07+02";5.74
    "2007-09-29 16:23:06+02";5.4
    "2007-09-29 16:25:07+02";6.39
    "2007-09-29 16:27:07+02";6.64
    "2007-09-29 16:29:07+02";6.3
    "2007-09-29 16:31:07+02";5.86
    "2007-09-29 16:33:07+02";5.62
    "2007-09-29 16:35:07+02";6.29
    "2007-09-29 16:37:07+02";5.24
    "2007-09-29 16:39:07+02";5.92
    "2007-09-29 16:41:07+02";5.68
    "2007-09-29 16:43:07+02";6.2
    "2007-09-29 16:45:07+02";6.53
    "2007-09-29 16:47:06+02";5.44
    "2007-09-29 16:49:06+02";5.58
    "2007-09-29 16:51:07+02";4.68
    "2007-09-29 16:53:07+02";6.36
    "2007-09-29 16:55:07+02";5.46
    "2007-09-29 16:57:06+02";5.4
    "2007-09-29 16:59:06+02";5.84
    "2007-09-29 17:01:06+02";6.12
    "2007-09-29 17:03:06+02";6.28
    "2007-09-29 17:05:06+02";5.48
    "2007-09-29 17:07:06+02";4.67
    "2007-09-29 17:09:06+02";4.69
    "2007-09-29 17:11:06+02";4.36
    "2007-09-29 17:13:06+02";4.6
    "2007-09-29 17:15:06+02";4.86
    "2007-09-29 17:17:06+02";4.52
    "2007-09-29 17:19:06+02";4.04
    "2007-09-29 17:21:06+02";3.98
    "2007-09-29 17:23:06+02";3.8
    "2007-09-29 17:25:06+02";3.76
    "2007-09-29 17:27:06+02";3.44
    "2007-09-29 17:29:06+02";3.44
    "2007-09-29 17:31:06+02";3.45
    "2007-09-29 17:33:06+02";3.64
    "2007-09-29 17:35:06+02";3.62
    "2007-09-29 17:37:06+02";3.43
    "2007-09-29 17:39:06+02";3.52
    "2007-09-29 17:41:06+02";3.31
    "2007-09-29 17:43:06+02";3.13
    "2007-09-29 17:45:06+02";3.21
    "2007-09-29 17:47:06+02";3.26
    "2007-09-29 17:49:06+02";3.17
    "2007-09-29 17:51:06+02";3.05
    "2007-09-29 17:53:06+02";2.86
    "2007-09-29 17:55:06+02";2.84
    "2007-09-29 17:57:06+02";2.79
    "2007-09-29 17:59:06+02";2.6
    "2007-09-29 18:01:06+02";2.54
    "2007-09-29 18:03:06+02";2.51
    "2007-09-29 18:05:06+02";2.54
    "2007-09-29 18:07:06+02";2.6
    "2007-09-29 18:09:06+02";2.5
    "2007-09-29 18:11:06+02";2.25
    "2007-09-29 18:13:06+02";2.26
    "2007-09-29 18:15:06+02";2.28
    "2007-09-29 18:17:06+02";1.95
    "2007-09-29 18:19:06+02";1.9
    "2007-09-29 18:21:06+02";1.8
    "2007-09-29 18:23:06+02";1.78
    "2007-09-29 18:25:06+02";1.56
    "2007-09-29 18:27:06+02";1.59
    "2007-09-29 18:29:06+02";1.55
    "2007-09-29 18:31:06+02";1.52
    "2007-09-29 18:33:06+02";1.48
    "2007-09-29 18:35:06+02";1.5
    "2007-09-29 18:37:06+02";1.44
    "2007-09-29 18:39:06+02";1.36
    "2007-09-29 18:41:06+02";1.34
    "2007-09-29 18:43:06+02";1.26
    "2007-09-29 18:45:06+02";1.2
    "2007-09-29 18:47:06+02";1.28
    "2007-09-29 18:49:06+02";1.34
    "2007-09-29 18:51:06+02";1.29
    "2007-09-29 18:53:06+02";1.36
    "2007-09-29 18:55:06+02";1.44
    "2007-09-29 18:57:06+02";1.43
    "2007-09-29 18:59:06+02";1.73
    "2007-09-29 19:01:06+02";1.94
    "2007-09-29 19:03:06+02";1.86
    "2007-09-29 19:05:06+02";1.88
    "2007-09-29 19:07:06+02";1.78
    "2007-09-29 19:09:06+02";1.52
    "2007-09-29 19:11:06+02";1.36
    "2007-09-29 19:13:06+02";1.28
    "2007-09-29 19:15:06+02";1.32
    "2007-09-29 19:17:06+02";1.24
    "2007-09-29 19:19:06+02";1.17
    "2007-09-29 19:21:06+02";1.16
    "2007-09-29 19:23:06+02";1.22
    "2007-09-29 19:25:06+02";1.18
    "2007-09-29 19:27:06+02";1.13
    "2007-09-29 19:29:06+02";1.06
    "2007-09-29 19:31:06+02";1.12
    "2007-09-29 19:33:06+02";1.16
    "2007-09-29 19:35:06+02";1.04
    "2007-09-29 19:37:06+02";0.98
    "2007-09-29 19:39:06+02";0.85
    "2007-09-29 19:41:06+02";0.85
    "2007-09-29 19:43:06+02";1.04
    "2007-09-29 19:45:06+02";0.97
    "2007-09-29 19:47:06+02";1.08
    "2007-09-29 19:49:06+02";1.2
    "2007-09-29 19:51:06+02";0.99
    "2007-09-29 19:53:06+02";0.86
    "2007-09-29 19:55:06+02";0.88
    "2007-09-29 19:57:06+02";0.86
    "2007-09-29 19:59:06+02";0.82
    "2007-09-29 20:01:06+02";0.89
    "2007-09-29 20:03:06+02";0.86
    "2007-09-29 20:05:06+02";0.94
    "2007-09-29 20:07:06+02";0.96
    "2007-09-29 20:09:06+02";1
    "2007-09-29 20:11:06+02";1.11
    "2007-09-29 20:13:06+02";1.06
    "2007-09-29 20:15:06+02";0.94
    "2007-09-29 20:17:06+02";1.18
    "2007-09-29 20:19:06+02";1.2
    "2007-09-29 20:21:06+02";1.05
    "2007-09-29 20:23:06+02";0.94
    "2007-09-29 20:25:06+02";1.02
    "2007-09-29 20:27:06+02";0.96
    "2007-09-29 20:29:06+02";0.85
    "2007-09-29 20:31:06+02";0.79
    "2007-09-29 20:33:06+02";0.92
    "2007-09-29 20:35:06+02";0.7
    "2007-09-29 20:37:06+02";0.78
    "2007-09-29 20:39:06+02";0.64
    "2007-09-29 20:41:06+02";0.54
    "2007-09-29 20:43:06+02";0.68
    "2007-09-29 20:45:06+02";0.58
    "2007-09-29 20:47:06+02";0.48
    "2007-09-29 20:49:06+02";0.46
    "2007-09-29 20:51:06+02";0.4
    "2007-09-29 20:53:06+02";0.5
    "2007-09-29 20:55:06+02";0.4
    "2007-09-29 20:57:06+02";0.49
    "2007-09-29 20:59:06+02";0.38
    "2007-09-29 21:01:06+02";0.32
    "2007-09-29 21:03:06+02";0.31
    "2007-09-29 21:05:06+02";0.22
    "2007-09-29 21:07:05+02";0.2
    "2007-09-29 21:09:05+02";0.17
    "2007-09-29 21:11:05+02";0.12
    "2007-09-29 21:13:05+02";0.22
    "2007-09-29 21:15:05+02";0.15
    "2007-09-29 21:17:05+02";0.18
    "2007-09-29 21:19:05+02";0.09
    "2007-09-29 21:21:05+02";-0.01
    "2007-09-29 21:23:05+02";-0.05
    "2007-09-29 21:25:05+02";0
    "2007-09-29 21:27:05+02";0.12
    "2007-09-29 21:29:05+02";0.09
    "2007-09-29 21:31:05+02";0.18
    "2007-09-29 21:33:05+02";0.04
    "2007-09-29 21:35:05+02";0.02
    "2007-09-29 21:37:05+02";-0.04
    "2007-09-29 21:39:05+02";-0.06
    "2007-09-29 21:41:05+02";0.06
    "2007-09-29 21:43:05+02";0.04
    "2007-09-29 21:45:05+02";0.04
    "2007-09-29 21:47:05+02";0.15
    "2007-09-29 21:49:05+02";0.22
    "2007-09-29 21:51:05+02";0.24
    "2007-09-29 21:53:05+02";0.22
    "2007-09-29 21:55:05+02";0.1
    "2007-09-29 21:57:05+02";0.11
    "2007-09-29 21:59:05+02";0.06
    "2007-09-29 22:01:05+02";0.09
    "2007-09-29 22:03:05+02";0.2
    "2007-09-29 22:05:05+02";0.11
    "2007-09-29 22:07:05+02";0.08
    "2007-09-29 22:09:05+02";0.08
    "2007-09-29 22:11:05+02";0.07
    "2007-09-29 22:13:05+02";0.06
    "2007-09-29 22:15:05+02";0.11
    "2007-09-29 22:17:05+02";0.12
    "2007-09-29 22:19:05+02";0.1
    "2007-09-29 22:21:05+02";0.19
    "2007-09-29 22:23:05+02";0.24
    "2007-09-29 22:25:05+02";0.24
    "2007-09-29 22:27:05+02";0.24
    "2007-09-29 22:29:05+02";0.22
    "2007-09-29 22:31:05+02";0.24
    "2007-09-29 22:33:05+02";0.28
    "2007-09-29 22:35:05+02";0.28
    "2007-09-29 22:37:05+02";0.26
    "2007-09-29 22:39:05+02";0.28
    "2007-09-29 22:41:05+02";0.28
    "2007-09-29 22:43:05+02";0.26
    "2007-09-29 22:45:05+02";0.27
    "2007-09-29 22:47:05+02";0.31
    "2007-09-29 22:49:05+02";0.29
    "2007-09-29 22:51:05+02";0.27
    "2007-09-29 22:53:05+02";0.3
    "2007-09-29 22:55:05+02";0.26
    "2007-09-29 22:57:05+02";0.26
    "2007-09-29 22:59:05+02";0.3
    "2007-09-29 23:01:05+02";0.3
    "2007-09-29 23:03:05+02";0.28
    "2007-09-29 23:05:05+02";0.22
    "2007-09-29 23:07:05+02";0.2
    "2007-09-29 23:09:05+02";0.16
    "2007-09-29 23:11:05+02";0.2
    "2007-09-29 23:13:05+02";0.2
    "2007-09-29 23:15:05+02";0.12
    "2007-09-29 23:17:05+02";0.08
    "2007-09-29 23:19:05+02";0.1
    "2007-09-29 23:21:05+02";0.14
    "2007-09-29 23:23:05+02";0.16
    "2007-09-29 23:25:05+02";0.27
    "2007-09-29 23:27:05+02";0.32
    "2007-09-29 23:29:05+02";0.34
    "2007-09-29 23:31:05+02";0.4
    "2007-09-29 23:33:05+02";0.37
    "2007-09-29 23:35:05+02";0.35
    "2007-09-29 23:37:05+02";0.32
    "2007-09-29 23:39:05+02";0.23
    "2007-09-29 23:41:05+02";0.26
    "2007-09-29 23:43:05+02";0.35
    "2007-09-29 23:45:05+02";0.31
    "2007-09-29 23:47:05+02";0.32
    "2007-09-29 23:49:05+02";0.3
    "2007-09-29 23:51:05+02";0.36
    "2007-09-29 23:53:05+02";0.33
    "2007-09-29 23:55:05+02";0.27
    "2007-09-29 23:57:05+02";0.27
    "2007-09-29 23:59:05+02";0.2
```

Expected results:

Hourly mean for 16 o'clock is : 5.7=5.36+5.80+6.06+5.70+5.58

```
2007-09-29 16:00  5.7
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work properly.

```
select date_trunc('hour', newest_time) as average_time,  
       (oldest_temp + middle_temp + newest_temp) / 3 as average_temp 
from (  
  select
     date_trunc('hour', dt) as average_time,
     lag(dt, 2) over w as oldest_time,
     lag(dt, 1) over w as middle_time,
     dt as newest_time,
     lag(ambtemp, 2) over w as oldest_temp,
     lag(ambtemp, 1) over w as middle_temp,
     ambtemp as newest_temp   
  from n32   
    window w as (order by dt) 
) as s 
where oldest_time = newest_time - '4 minutes'::interval 
  and middle_time = newest_time - '2 minutes'::interval 
  and extract(minute from newest_time) in (2, 3);
```

Comment: Try using `lag()` and `lead()` function from [`this`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) page to get 2 values before and 2 values after.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko and question is updated

Comment: @Catcall, question is updated

Comment: Try this steps: 1) For every record find average of 5 values (`lag(2), lag(1), current, lead(1), lead(2)`). 2) From the results of first step for every hour get the vales, that are the closes to the start of the hour.

Comment: I can't find the *table definition* in your question. And the *version* of PostgreSQL. Also clarify your contradicting question: 5 minute interval before and after every full hour or two trailing and two preceding values?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, the version of the software is 9.2. I meant hourly mean of 6 o'clock is average of correspondent values to 5:55, 5:57, 5:59 , 6:01 and 6:03.

Comment: So I take it you want the 5 minute interval before and after every full hour, no matter how many rows are actually found. Both answers are based on that interpretation.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, Yes it doesn't matter how many rows are they but the sampling frequency is 2 minute, so we should have totally 5 observation.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, would u plz guide me in this question?

Comment: I think your problem is that you keep changing [your](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14316547/131874) [requirements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14274595/131874). Either you don't quite understand your problem or you are trying to impose a solution. In instead show some real data and your final objective and you will get more focused answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start with, you have two completely different sets of requirements. These two things aren't the same.

- 5 minutes before and 5 minutes after each hour.
- 2 observations before and 2 observations after each hour.

The second one relies on your sampling *never* failing to be within the two-minute sample intervals. I would not only bet that someday your sampling *will* fail that two-minute interval, I'll bet it already has. Sampling might fail for many reasons, but 5-minute intervals of time can *never* fail to be 5-minute intervals of time. Use the first one, not the second one.

This query generates one bucket per hour, and averages all the readings that fall within 5 minutes of the hour. It includes both endpoints. That is, for 16:00, it includes both 15:55 and 16:05.

```
with buckets as (
  select '00:00'::time + (n || ' hours')::interval bucket
  from generate_series(0,23) n
)
select b.bucket, avg(t.observation) obs_avg
from buckets b
inner join test t 
        on test_ts::time between (bucket - interval '5' minute) 
                             and (bucket + interval '5' minute)
group by bucket;

bucket    obs_avg
--
16:00:00  5.7
17:00:00  5.82
```

If your values aren't normally distributed--and they don't *appear* to be normally distributed--you should use the median instead of average. Median is a better indication of central tendency when your values aren't normally distributed.  You'll need to [create a function](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median) for that; PostgreSQL doesn't have a native median function.

---

> My tables name is s_25 and time-date table is dt and variable is
>   ambtemp

Based on that late comment, and assuming you meant your timestamp column is dt, here's my best guess.

```
with buckets as (
  select '00:00'::time + (n || ' hours')::interval bucket
  from generate_series(0,23) n
)
select b.bucket, avg(t.ambtemp) obs_avg
from buckets b
inner join s_25 t 
        on dt::time between (bucket - interval '5' minute) 
                        and (bucket + interval '5' minute)
group by bucket
```

If you're going to run this query over multiple dates, joining on time alone won't be sufficient. Use this instead. The CTEs "even_hours" and "obs_dates" return the pieces that are cross-joined in "bucket_midpoints" to return all the hours for the dates you're interested in. The WHERE clause in "obs_dates" keeps you from generating too many rows.

```
with even_hours as (
  select '00:00'::time + (n || ' hour')::interval as obs_time
  from generate_series(0, 23) n
), 
obs_dates as (
  select distinct (dt)::date obs_date
  from s_25
  -- *This* WHERE clause keeps you from generating too many rows
  -- for the join below. You *could* select the min and max dates
  -- from your table, but you'd probably get too many rows that way.
  where dt between '2007-09-01' and '2007-09-30'
), 
bucket_midpoints as (
  select (obs_dates.obs_date || ' ' || even_hours.obs_time)::timestamp as bucket_midpoint
  from obs_dates, even_hours
)
select (bucket_midpoint - interval '5' minute) bucket_start,
       (bucket_midpoint + interval '5' minute) bucket_end,
       avg(s_25.ambtemp)
from bucket_midpoints
left join s_25
       on s_25.dt between (bucket_midpoint - interval '5' minute)
                      and (bucket_midpoint + interval '5' minute)
group by bucket_start, bucket_end
order by bucket_start, bucket_end
```

Comment: I cannot fit the data to the code. Would u plz guide me in this matter. My tables name is s_25 and time-date table is dt and variable is ambtemp.

Comment: The number of outputs are also not correct. With respect to my db there should be let us say 60 hourly average while the code results only 25. Moreover, the results are not correct. The sample data in the question is a subset of data and it doesn't work for whole data.

Comment: YEs. I have at least two days in each table. Average column also not shows any value.

Comment: Average column has no value for 2007-09-29 15:55:00?

Comment: It has the data : "2007-09-29 15:55:06+02";5.36

Comment: That's right. The average column shows values where there are values to average. Otherwise it shows nothing. That's what it *should* do.

Comment: That is amazing, the data is availble for a long time period why it could not show result?

Comment: No data within 5 minutes of the hour, between the dates '2007-09-01' and '2007-09-30'?

Comment: But the data in the question is on the 2007-09-29

Answer (score 1):

This is just a much simpler version of what [@Catcall already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14435394/939860) (correctly):

```
WITH h AS (
   SELECT g - interval '5m' AS lo
         ,g + interval '5m' AS hi
   FROM   generate_series('2007-09-29 15:00'::timestamp  -- abs. dt range ..
                        , '2007-09-29 18:00'::timestamp  -- from / to
                        , interval '1h') AS g
   )
SELECT lo, hi
     , to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch FROM s.dt))) AS avg_dt
     , round(avg(s.ambtemp)::numeric, 4) AS avg_ambtemp
FROM   h
LEFT   JOIN s_25 s ON s.dt BETWEEN lo AND hi
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2
```

[->sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/80185/3)

If you don't want to list hours where no matching rows are found, replace the `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`.

Comment: I came up with this error:  ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 8: SELECT lo, hi, round(avg(s.ambtemp), 4) AS avg_ambtemp
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @Amidi: Did you not see my questions in the comment or did you chose to ignore them? And why should I be interested in your questions while you refuse to cooperate? The problem you are facing is a direct consequence of you not providing the information I requested .. and it's a trivial one ..

Comment: I am so sorry, you are right. I did not see your comment. I do apologize!

Comment: @Amidi: Cast to `numeric` for `round()`. round() is just for  formatting and not strictly needed. You can also remove it. As you can see in the sqlfiddle it works with `numeric` data.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is it possible to create the time in the way that assign an instantaneous time to average value. For example: Average for these time sequences : "2007-09-29 14:55:06+02";5.54
"2007-09-29 14:57:06+02";5.53
"2007-09-29 14:59:06+02";5.5
"2007-09-29 15:01:06+02";5.33
"2007-09-29 15:03:06+02";6.18
 result   "2007-09-29 15:00:00"; 5.616

Comment: @Amidi: Yes, convert to unix epoch for the avg. I added it to my answer and updated the fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gave wrong averages. I have updated the question with whole my dataset.

Comment: @Amidi; You can see in the sqlfiddle that it works correctly. Maybe another problem with the data type - I suspect `timestamp with time zone`. I did ask for the **table definition**. You did not respond to that. It should all be **in your question**. More sample data does not help.

Comment: Yes the time_date columns format is timestamp without time zone.